# How to check if a string contains only numbers in Postscript

Tags: string, numbers, compare, postscript

I am struggeling on how to comfortably check if a string in Postscript for example `(123456)`
contains only numbers. e.g. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9.

so for example:

`(1235) isnum` should put true on the stack

`(1234a) isnum` should put false on the stack

`(1.234) isnum` should put false on the stack

Do I really have to use a loop to check every single character if it is inside of (0-9) like this:

```
/integers (0123456789) def

% checks if a char is in (0123456789)
/isnum
{
    integers exch search
    { pop pop pop true }
    { pop false }ifelse
}
def

 /isnumber {
                        % [(number),(number)]
    length 1 sub        % [(number), length-1]
    0 exch              % [(number), 0, length-1]
    1 exch              % [(number), 0, 1, length-1]
    
    % [(number), 0, 1, length-1]
    
    dup /numlen exch 1 add def
    /counter 0 def
    
    % for(j=0; j<length-1; j++)
    {
        /j exch def
                        % [(number)]
                        
        dup j 1 getinterval     % [(number), number[j]] 
        /char exch def          % [(number)] && char == number[j]   

        char isnum {
            /counter counter 1 add def
        }if
    
    }for
    
    counter numlen eq
    {
        true
    }
    {
        false
    }ifelse
}def
```

(12345) (12345) isnumber ==> true is on the stack

Or is there any faster procedure?

Answer (score 2):

There's another style of writing this kind of code that takes advantage of the fact that postscript's relational operators work on strings as well.

So, if you can peel off the characters one by one using `getinterval` to make length=1 strings, you can compare them directly with `(0)` or `(9)`.

```
/isdigit { dup (0) ge exch (9) le and } def
```

This makes the "map" step from my other answer a little more complicated.

```
/foreach { % array/string proc
  1 dict begin { /proc /str }{ exch def }forall   % define args
  0 1 /str load length 1 sub     % 3 numbers for `for` later
  ( { //str exch 1 getinterval
      //proc exec } )            % template loop body
  cvx exec                       % generate loop body from template
  end for                        % discard dict then call `for`
} def
/isnumber { true exch { isdigit and } foreach } def
```

And this leads to another idea. If there's a reasonable maximum length for the strings you're working with, you could compare with zeroes or nines, ie. `(0000)` and `(9999)` for a string of length=4.

```
/zeros (000000000) def
/nines (999999999) def
/isnumber { dup zeros 0 2 index length getinterval ge exch
                nines 0 2 index length getinterval le and } def
```

With this way, `ge` and `le` are implicitly doing the loops over the string contents to do their job.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a program fragment ready to customize. This checks each character in a string for being a numeral. The numerals in a string are integers from 48 to 57:

```
(345fd2) { dup 48 ge exch 57 le and = } forall
```

This is just a starting point. The result from each element in a string can be accumulated and checked as desired. Have fun.

EDIT: This leaves false on the stack if the string fails the test or nothing at all if passing:

```
 /isnumb {{dup 48 ge exch 57 le and not{false exit}if} forall} def
```

EDIT2: This does what you asked. There might be an easier way if I only knew.

```
/isnumber? { { dup 48 ge exch 57 le and
             {/flag true def}{/flag false def exit} ifelse
             } forall
           flag
           } def
```

EDIT3: Thanks luser droog for the code where I learned how to eliminate the flag. Any empty string passes the test so beware. Still looking at the stopped and stop.

```
/isnumber { true exch
            { dup 48 ge exch 57 le and   % element is digit 
              not{pop false exit}if      % element is not digit
            } forall
          } def
```

EDIT4: This leaves false on the stack for a zero length string:

```
/isnumeric { dup length 0 eq
            { pop false              % false for zero length string
            }{
             true exch
             {dup 48 ge exch 57 le and
             not{pop false exit}if   % early exit for non-digit
             } forall                % check each element of string
            } ifelse
           } def
```

EDIT5: Thanks again luser droog for clues making me really think. This still leaves true on the stack for zero length string:

```
/isnum {true exch {dup 48 ge exch 57 le and and}forall } def
```

EDIT6: Thanks again for the information about the stopped and the rest too. That is very helpful. I need more time to study and experiment.

I added a test in case the operator is used on things other than strings so returns false for things like arrays instead of complaining:

```
/isnums { 
         {dup type /stringtype ne {stop} if
           dup length 0 ne exch
           {dup 48 ge exch 57 le and and}forall
         }stopped {pop false}if
        } def
```

EDIT7: Finally. This works too.

```
/isnumbr { 
          {dup type /stringtype ne {pop false stop} if
           dup length 0 ne exch
           {dup 48 ge exch 57 le and and}forall
          }stopped not and
         } def
```

Comment: Good stuff. You might want to investigate `stopped`. Something like `{ { ... } loop } stopped` would let you call `stop` to bail out of the loop and `stopped` will yield a boolean letting you know whether ` stop` was called or not. Also, see my answer for another approach.

Comment: Added an example of `stopped` to my answer.

Comment: For some examples and explanation of `stopped`, see [this post of mine](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/WOX5SWug5R8/discussion) which has material that was written for SO's Documentation project. It's the key to understanding and using error handling in PS.

Comment: For the "EDIT5" code, you could easily add a check for zero length. Just use the result for the initial boolean, the `true`. ie. `{ dup length 0 ne exch { dup...} forall }`

Comment: I added an EDIT6 with both the stopped and the length check added. Just ran out of time tonight.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a *map-reduce* strategy. For the base case, checking one character:

```
/isdigit { dup 48 ge exch 57 le and } def  % int . bool
```

Then, we can do a map with this procedure over the string.

```
/map { [ 3 1 roll forall ] } def  % string proc . array
```

This yields an array of booleans, one for each character of the string. To collapse this array into a single boolean, we can *reduce* the array with an initial element and a binary operation.

```
/reduce { exch 3 1 roll forall } def  % array initial proc . result
```

All together:

```
/isnumber { //isdigit map  true {and} reduce } def  % string . bool

(1234) isnumber
```

NB. This code will report `true` for an empty string since it doesn't contain any non-digit characters. `//isdigit` above could also be written `{isdigit}` but using the immediately-loaded name avoids creating a new array here. This cannot be done with `and` since it is likely to be an operator and thus not a compatible type for `forall`.

This could be made more efficient by combining the two `forall` loops and eliminating the array of booleans. But this code doesn't have the early exiting behavior exhibited in beginner6789's answer.

```
/isnumber { true exch { isdigit and } forall } def
```

EDIT: **How to use `stopped` for this**

To add early exit behavior, we can make use of the `{ ... stop ... } stopped` construct which lets us bail out of the middle of a loop (or any code) and automatically provides a boolean.

```
/isnumber { { { isdigit not {stop} if } forall } stopped not } def
```

or, with clearer indentation,

```
/isnumber {
  {
    {
      isdigit not {stop} if      % if any of the individual tests fail, stop
    } forall
  } stopped                      % yields true if stop was called
  not                            % reverse the boolean,
                                 %  so now false==stop was called
} def
```

Similar could be done with just `exit` and stack juggling.

```
/isnumber {
  true exch
  {
    isdigit not { pop false exit } if
  } forall
} def
```